# I'm stuck, can i make $_GET dynamic?

Tags: ajax, get

I want to know if i can make $_GET['THIS VALUE'] dynamic so i dont have to write the validation for each field

i have this in javascript:

```
function check_if_exists(input_name) {

var ajaxRequest;

 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange=function() {

if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('info');
    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
}

}

var name = document.getElementById(input_name).value;

var url = "?"+input_name+"=" + name;

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "example_validation.php" + url, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);

}
```

and then in the php i have a SQL similar to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username='".$input_value."' LIMIT 1";
```

now, i want to take whatever the name of $_GET is and passing it into a variable an replace it with the username from the SQL.

Is it possible or i have to write a validation for each field?

Comment: Even if you were to find a way to make this possible, it's probably not a good idea.  You should explicitly reference your input values, and explicitly validate them.  Especially if you're going to concatenate them into a SQL query like that.

Comment: i made it, since i have only two fields that i have to check, that is username and email i made some if statements and it work, i think is no risk because im going to escape the values of $input_type and the other values i get them only from my code, is not something that user types in...

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the user has to type it in.  What matters is that they *can*.  (I've done exactly that several times, tweaking field names in the HTML in order to get around half-assed validation.)  *Nothing* in `$_GET` should be trusted without checking it explicitly.  And that includes form field *names* as well as values.